# SQL LIKE кроме цифр в %

Tags: mysql, sql

подскажите как выбрать только те записи, где есть `1`

Такой запрос возвращает ещё те записи, где 1, 10, 11 и т.д.

```
SELECT * FROM `table` where value like '%1%'
```

```
| id | value    |
| 1  | 4,10     |
| 2  | 3,10,9,2 |
| 3  | 3,4,2,1  |
| 4  | 3,4,1,2  |
| 5  | 3,4,10,2  |
```

Т.е вернуть только записи с id равен 3 или 4

Comment: `WHERE FIND_IN_SET('1', column)`

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно именно через `like`, то нужно добавить с обеих сторон и от шаблона и от исходной строки разделители

```
SELECT * FROM `table` where CONCAT(',', value, ',') like '%,1,%'
```

Comment: а `1,%` и `%,1` не  надо?

Comment: @teran, нет, потому что я добавил запятые перед первым и после последнего элемента. В моем варианте граничные случаи совпадают с общими, и отдельно их проверять не нужно.

Comment: а да, не обратил внимания.

Answer (score 1):

Вот способ через Regex

```
select * from table where value Regexp "((^|[,])pattern(($|[,])))+"
```

где pattern искомое значение